# OpenCv first steps - no suitable constructor exists to convert from "IplImage *" to "cv::_InputArray"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I used OpenCv with version of 2.4.1. When I try to do something like that:

```
Mat graySmallOutputImage = cvarrToMat(smallImageGray);
cvMoveWindow("face", 0, 0);
imshow("face", graySmallOutputImage);
namedWindow("result", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cvMoveWindow("result", 500, 500);
Mat image = cvarrToMat(image);
imshow("result", image);
```

I get a error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error (active)      no suitable constructor exists to convert from "IplImage *" to "cv::_InputArray

[image]

Unfortunately I can not find a solution to this problem. Any tips?

Comment: Don't use obsolete C api!

Comment: Which function do you mean?

Comment: Everything that uses `IplImage`, and basically every function that starts with cv<FunctionName>

Comment: @Miki OpenCv functions is deprecated? Wtf?

Comment: Obsolete C api is deprecated. You should use OpenCV C++ api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow):

[image]

You see how the `C` version of the method, `cvMoveWindow` is dimmed? That's because the C API is deprecated. It should not be used for writing new code. The equivalent C++ method, `moveWindow`, should be used instead. In general, C functions will look like `cvFunctionName`. If you see `cv` at the beginning, double check with the documentation.

Comment: But I got an error in the function imshow as well see.

Comment: That's because you the C API creates an `IplImage` rather than the C++ `Mat` and there is no longer a `Mat` constructor that takes an `IplImage`.